# Docker service in swarm fails with error ask: non-zero exit (1)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When we run command  :

```
docker service create --name [name] --with-registry-auth image-name
```

Services fails with Error - non-zero exit (1)

> docker version - Docker version 1.12.2

Comment: That's not a valid command. Is that actually the command you ran, or did you change it to post here?

Comment: @BMitch `docker service create` absolutely is a valid command; it's a part of Docker Swarm.

Comment: @user5702955 Is the image you're trying to run public? Please include it if it is.

Comment: @tjbiddle it is with the proper arguments. But the question above didn't include the correct arguments.

Comment: @BMitch I'm not sure what you mean - `docker service create --name test_service nginx` works fine for me.

Comment: @TJBiddle The `[name]` would throw an error, but honestly I didn't see the `image-name` on the end of their question before, I may just be going blind. Regardless, without an exact copy/paste of the command being run and error message seen, this may not be answerable.

Comment: Ah - yeah, `[name]` would definitely mess things up; I just took that as a placeholder.

Answer (score 27):

try `docker service logs [name]` to get a more detailed message why your service failed.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

The quick easy way to follow and see logs with docker swarm is by using

```bash
docker service logs --follow [SERVICE_NAME | SERVICE_ID]
```

This command open an interactive terminal(`STDOUT`) on your shell to show all logs applications running inside this service

I don't recommend the usage of `docker service logs [SERVICE_NAME | SERVICE_ID]`, Since the service might be crashing early at the beginning where it was able to yet log the messages before the container crashes, but with `--follow` option all logs are shown!

Comment: I had to use the service ID rather than its name (`docker service ls` to find).

Comment: Yeah, Service ID or name can be used to identify a service on docker, thanks for the add up!